# Making my own haarcascade

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, haar-classifier

I know how to use already made haarcascades for face,eyes detection etc. But I wanted to create a **haarcascade to recognize a ceiling fan**(both when it is turned ON or OFF). Can anyone give me some good suggestions on how can I make such a haarcascade?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I followed this video and made Haarcascades for bikes and heavy vehicle detection and it was helpful

[SentDex Making our own HaarCascades](https://youtu.be/eay7CgPlCyo)

Comment: Please add a minimal explanation in the answer itself, as the link provided may happen to unavailable in the future.